# NOT IN() returns weird result in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql statement:

```
SELECT  `review_userid` ,  `book_id` ,  `review_id` ,  `user_class` , COUNT( review_id ) 
FROM  `booklist_books` 
LEFT JOIN  `booklist_reviews` ON booklist_books.book_id = booklist_reviews.review_bookid
LEFT JOIN  `e107_user` ON booklist_reviews.review_userid = e107_user.user_id
WHERE '12' NOT IN (`user_class`)
GROUP BY  `review_userid` 
ORDER BY COUNT(`review_id`) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

`user_class` is a comma-delimited string (e.g: 1,2,3,4,5), as you can see below.

Using phpmyadmin, I get the following result:

[image: mysql result]

Why do I get results that have '12' in the user_class field since I am using `'12' NOT IN(...`  ??

If I can't user `user_class` in the IN() operator, what is the alternative to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IN` or `NOT IN` is not working like that, check the function [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('12', `user_class`) = 0
```

Comment: I want it NOT to have the '12' in the list, so it is = 0. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is expr IN (value,...)

```
WHERE `user_class` NOT IN ('12')
```

If two or more tables use the same column name, it is ambiguous and you should need to prefix or nick name your tables to clearly define which column you are calling.

```
WHERE table.column NOT IN ('12')
```

Nick name:

```
SELECT table a, table2 b
```

Comment: This also works! Too bad I can't select 2 answers :P Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

`value IN (...)` checks to see if `value` is one of the items listed in `(...)`. In your case, the list only contains one value: the value of the `user_class` column. The string `'12'` is not equal to the string `'3,6,9,12'`, so it finds no match. `IN` is not searching for matching substrings in the column's value.

Because you have multiple comma-separated values in one field, you'd want to employ [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

---

If you have the option of restructuring the data, you should employ [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to avoid this mess of having multiple values in one field.